# What's the library should I import for UTTypeImage, which is the replacement of kUTTypeImage in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Before iOS 15, I used UIImagePickerController to capture images and video, and I got mediaType from `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`, then I used `kUTTypeImage` (in the `MobileCoreServices` library) to identify the mediaType.

However, When it comes to iOS 15, Xcode complains that `kUTTypeImage was deprecated in iOS 15.0. Use UTTypeImage instead.` So, I replaced `kUTTypeImage` with `UTTypeImage`, but Xcode didn't know it.

Tried searching for some information, but didn't get any clue. I guess I should import the right library, but what is it?

Here is part of the code：

```swift
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? String else { return }
        switch mediaType {
        case String(kUTTypeImage):
        // blabla
        case String(kUTTypeMovie):
        // blabla
```

and here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a bit confusing. First, you'll need to `import UniformTypeIdentifiers`. Then, replace `kUTTypeImage` with [`UTType.image`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551508-image) (the Swift version of [`UTTypeImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypeimage)).

Comment: And instead of `case String(UTType.image):`, I think it should be `case UTType.image.identifier:`.

Comment: Im glad they are switching to using UniformTypeIdentifiers instead of the old MobileCoreServices

Comment: For Objective C, this answer was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520873/612794

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a replacement of URL extension like in this post:

[iOS15 UTType deprecations for URL-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540672/ios15-uttype-deprecations-for-url-extension)

here you go with a way shorter version

```swift
import Foundation
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension URL {
   
    func mimeType() -> String {
        let pathExtension = self.pathExtension
        if let type = UTType(filenameExtension: pathExtension) {
            if let mimetype = type.preferredMIMEType {
                return mimetype as String
            }
        }
        return "application/octet-stream"
    }
    
    
    func conforms(to type: UTType) -> Bool{
        let uttype = UTType(mimeType: mimeType())
        
        return uttype?.conforms(to: type) ?? false
        
        
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
url.conforms(to: .json)
```