# Where can I find the official UTTypeItem constant?

Tags: swift

It's possible to register an `NSView` for all dragged types using the elusive `UTTypeItem` which allegedly replaces `kUTTypeItem` pasteboard type (now deprecated).

However, when I specify `UTTypeItem`, the Swift compiler tells me that it can't find this constant.

Eg:  `controlView.registerForDraggedTypes([UTTypeItem])`  gives an error

When I try and compile this code, the Swift compiler helpfully says, "Did you mean `kUTTypeItem` ?", which gets me nowhere, of course.  I tried importing `CoreServices` but couldn't find it there.

After a bit of digging, I found that I could define `UTTypeItem` for myself using a rawValue as below:

`private let UTTypeItem = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init("public.item")`

"public.item" is, of course, the under-the-covers value of `UTTypeItem`.  This works fine, and the compiler is happy, but I think this approach is inelegant.

So my question is: where can I fing the "official" location of `UTTypeItem` ?

Dave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the library should I import for UTTypeImage, which is the replacement of kUTTypeImage in iOS 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332404/whats-the-library-should-i-import-for-uttypeimage-which-is-the-replacement-of)

Comment: Thanks HangarRash.  It doesn't settle the issue for me, but the comments in that thread pointed me at the need to import UniformTypeIdentifiers, which is useful in itself.  

But if I specify UTType.item (declared inside UniformTypeIdentifiers) I still get the compiler error "Cannot convert value of type 'UTType' to expected element type 'Array<NSPasteboard.PasteboardType>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'NSPasteboard.PasteboardType')".

So despite, what Xcode says,  kUTTypeItem is not directly equivalent to  UTType.item, or UTTypeItem, wherever it may hide.

Comment: You would want `UTTypeItem.identifier` to get the string value needed by the pasteboard.

Comment: I assume you mean UTType.item, which will indeed give the UTType I need.  But it's still a UTType, not a string value!  Thus, I remain with my original code.  I'm just making the point that the compiler messages suggest there should be a UTTypeItem constant somewhere, and it remains elusive.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use `UTType` you need to import `UniformTypeIdentifiers`:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```

This will then give you access to `UTType.item`. But since you need a `String` to pass it to the `NSPasteboard`, you need to access the `identifier` property.

```
let uti = UTType.item.identifier // Gives "public.item"
let pasteboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(uti)
```

If you need this is more than one place in your project you can add an extension:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension NSPasteboard.PasteboardType {
    static let item = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(UTType.item.identifier)
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
controlView.registerForDraggedTypes([ .item ])
```

Comment: That's great Hangar - that makes things much clearer and fully answers my question.  I will follow your pattern of using an extension on NSPasteboard.PasteboardType since this makes it convenient to use these pasteboard types from multiple places within the same app.